# edmx validation throws an error about collide primary key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx

I have 3 entities: `BaseUser`, `AuthenticationUser` and `User`. `AuthenticationUser` inherit from `BaseUser` and `User` inherit from `AuthenticationUser`. `User` entity has scalar property of type Binary (photo) so I would like to split the `User` entity into `User` and `UserPhoto`.

I did exactly what this nice article sais: http://www.deveducate.com/blog/post/2010/12/14/Entity-Framework-Modeling-Table-Splitting.aspx

Here is an image of my edmx:
[image]

When I validate the edmx I keep getting this error:

```
Error 3033: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 13058:EntitySets 'UserPhotoes' and 'BaseUsers' are both mapped to table 'T_USER'. Their primary keys may collide.
```

What is the meanning of this error?
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Does UserPhoto have the same discriminator value as User?

Comment: @GertArnold: UserPhoto entity use tbl_users table the same as User entity. Therefore they both have the same PK.